# form submit and ajax in validated form

Tags: php, html, ajax

i have this function to prevent form to submit if not validated but then when its ok the ajax is not exexuted

```
$(function () {
    $('#contact-form').validator();

    $('#contact-form').submit(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
 if(! $('#contact-form')[0].valid())  return false;

    var surname = $("#search_text").val();
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var mail = $("#mail").val();
    $("#printableArea").show();

    html2canvas([document.getElementById('printableArea')], {
  onrendered: function(canvas) {

        var imagedata = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        var imgdata = imagedata.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
  // upload to imgur using jquery/CORS
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/En/HTTP_access_control

$("#register").val("Please wait to send the Subscription")
  $.ajax({
      url: 'save_image.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
    imgdata:imgdata,surname:surname,name:name,mail:mail
         },

  }).success(function(data) {
 $('#contact-form')[0].submit();
  }).error(function() {
      alert('Could not send the form');
     w.close();

  });
  },
  });

    });
});
```

if i remove  `if(! $('#contact-form')[0].valid())  return false;` the form is validated but ajax is executed.
How i can do both wright. I ve searched all the same questions but none of them worked

Comment: What happens with `if(! $('#contact-form')[0].checkValidity())  return false;`?

Comment: happens that if form is validated then ajax is not executed

Comment: `$('#contact-form')[0]` change to `$('#contact-form')` ?

Comment: doesn't do anything of both